# Change input value throwing an event with js

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I've an input field that can be modify by users and js buttons. 
I need to throw an event when the user writes/deletes something in the textarea and when a button modifies the value of the input without using jQuery.

I tried to overwrite input's get and set methods but when I change input text with js before modify it by my hand and change it again with js the displayed text in the input box doesn't change.

It has to work on IE11 and Chrome (cannot use `onpropertychange` event).

https://jsfiddle.net/gzmdc3zz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an '[oninput](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp)' and an '[onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)' in javascript. Try one of these:

```
object.oninput=function(){myScript};
```

**Edit:**
I think there is no true solution for this, but you can try the hack on this [link](http://justyouraveragegeek.com/blog/index.php/2011/03/property-changed-event-on-javascript-objects/) instead of your manipulated setters/getters. 
In this case you get an event-callback whenever the given property of an element has changed **programmatically** (with new and old value).

You can then change the value on the original element by yourself or do whatever you want. In addition you then need a normal .oninput-event on the element,too. To get the event from user inputs.

If anyone has a better idea how to manage this, I'm looking forward to read it.

Comment: OP has asked for a solution without jquery.

Comment: well your fiddle is working well, as i understood your question. What exactly are your needs?

Comment: Try this:
- click button
- modify input text
- click button

Comment: well that is some really odd behaviour. If you inspect the input-element with the browser, the value changes allright, but it's not proper displayed. It's because of your modified getter and setter settings!

Comment: Exactly but the value doesn't change if you modify the input text manually.
Anyway how can I solve that?! T.T

Comment: I think it is because of the modified setters only handle code-changed values.If you print out an alert("") in the setter, it only prompts, if you click the button, not if you are changing the text manually. So you own-defined property "value" is never changed when changing the text by user input. So in short: changes from user-inputs itself are ignoring your setters

Comment: Yes, and how I can define a set that triggers on users-inputs?

Comment: I edited my post with some ideas, sorry that i can't give you a true solution, I'm out of ideas :/